# PHP echo not working in POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an input field using bootstrap and some more libraries (see below for HTML, yes it is dutch). The data from this field is send to my PHP using jQuery (see below). I use the jQuery to convert the markdown input to HTML, using showdown.

The PHP makes a file in which the correct input data is stored seperated by '|'s. The 'author' input is optional. This all works fine

The problem that arises is that I want to give feedback to the user, using an echo. Only, this does not appear to be done?! All other functions in the PHP do get executed, it creates a file in the targeted directory, except the echo.

I cannot find an answer here on Stackoverflow or anywhere else. What am I doing wrong?

### HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    Nieuw artikel toevoegen
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class='edit'>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            <div class='input-group'>
                <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Kop*</span>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Kop' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' id='title'>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class='input-group'>
                <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Datum*</span>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Datum' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' id='date'>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class='input-group'>
                <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Auteur (evt.)</span>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Auteur (evt.)' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' id='author'>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <h4>Inhoud van het artikel*</h4>
                <textarea name='textArt' data-provide='markdown' language='nl' rows='20' id='text'></textarea>
            </div>
            <!--<input type='file' id='filetag'>-->
            <br>
            <button name='save' class='btn btn-default' id='submit'>Opslaan</button><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            //Request input
            var author = $("#author").val();
            var date = $("#date").val();
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var markdown = $("#text").val();

            //Convert Markdown to HTML
            var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
            html = converter.makeHtml(markdown);

            //Send input
            if($.post("edit.php?loc=nieuws", {text: html, title: title, date: date, author: author})){
                console.log("succes");
            }
        })
    })
```

### PHP

```
if ($_POST['text'] != "") {
    $directory = "some_target_dir/";

    $articles = scandir($directory);

    $num_files = count($articles) - 2;

    $int = $num_files + 1;

    $dir = $directory.$int.".txt";

    $end = $_POST['date']."|".$_POST['title']."|".$_POST['text'];

    if(!$_POST['author'] == "") {

        $end = $end."|".$_POST['author'];

    }

    $file = fopen($dir, "w") or die("Oops a mistake");

    fwrite($file, $end);

    fclose($file);

    //This one doesn't work?!
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Succes!</div>';
}
```

Comment: Is the php code from the edit.php file?

Comment: Any errors? Does `fclose($file);` work?

Comment: `fwrite($file, $end)` works, php gives no errors and no errors in console in chrome

Comment: @RST Yes it is (it is actually in a seperate file but gets included to edit.php, so yeah it is). The form is in the same file (also gets included into edit.php).

Comment: Your structure is most likely the problem. Right now it is like talking to someone who already left the room. If edit.php is the file that handles everything than you should let that file set a variable or something and feed it into the HTML.

Comment: @RST how would you advise doing this? Should I process the send POST  differently (using a different if)? Or should i put a variable to true instead of the echo and put the echo later on? My current structure is: edit.php gives form -> User input gets send back to edit.php -> edit.php processes it -> edit.php confirms it worked. What should I change?

Comment: You could use the php file directly instead of sending it to edit.php. Then on success, instead of putting some text to the console.log you could update a div, you add to your html file, with the updated success message. Or have the success message in the html file already and just hide it first and then show on success. This way you don't experience the reload of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a part of your PHP code is failing, debug what's returning like this:

```
$.post("url", {params}).done(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    // This will show you what the returning output is.
});
```

Edit: change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //Request input
            var author = $("#author").val();
            var date = $("#date").val();
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var markdown = $("#text").val();

            //Convert Markdown to HTML
            var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
            html = converter.makeHtml(markdown);

            //Send input
            if($.post("edit.php?loc=nieuws", {text: html, title: title, date: date, author: author})){
                console.log("succes");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: When running this in the console the results does contain the wanted HTML. However, when I change my PHP to this, the result gets put into the console and immediately disappears because the page is reloaded.

Comment: I had some technical problems, but I just tested your solution. As far as i can see it works fine, but the echo still does not work. The page does not reload anymore but it does not give any feedback. The file does get made and written to.